# Setting up Angular child routes with dynamic first part

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

So as a recent project, I'm trying to setup a blogging system. The next part I'm trying to tackle is the admin part, mainly editing posts.

My idea was to have the routes work like this:

1. **/blog** - This is where the home-page would be.
2. **/blog/:slug** - This is how you'd access the individual posts
3. **/blog/admin** - This is how you'd access the admin section

Here's the current routes that I'm using:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: BlogHomeComponent},
  {path: 'admin', component: BlogAdminComponent},
  {
    path: ':slug', component: PostComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'edit',
        component: PostEditComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

As stated before, what I'm trying to setup now is the 'edit post' section. I was thinking of setting something like:

**/blog/:slug/edit**

So an actual URL could look like: /blog/post-title-thing-im-talking-about/edit

So that I could easily just append /edit to the end of each post and edit it.

The way it is currently setup doesn't work. It attempts to load the page and then just routes 'out of' the blog module and goes to my next one (Projects). so that it routes like:

```
/blog/projects
```

Here's the routing for my app.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'blog',
    loadChildren: './blog/blog.module#BlogModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'projects',
    loadChildren: './projects/projects.module#ProjectsModule'
  },
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent}

];
```

My guess is that it is actually looking for a URL pattern like "/blog/blog-post-title/edit" instead of just matching /blog/***/edit. As I've tried a few different routing setups and its returned errors like:

"/blog/blog-post-name-thing/edit" doesn't exist as a current route.

Is there a way to setup that sort of dynamic routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're configuring things, the edit component would be displayed inside the template of the PostComponent, next to a router-outlet directive inside this template. You don't want that. You want it to be a separate page. So it should simply be

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: BlogHomeComponent},
  {path: 'admin', component: BlogAdminComponent},
  {path: ':slug', component: PostComponent},
  {path: ':slug/edit', component: PostEditComponent}
];
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok. So when you setup children like that, it'll get rendered INSIDE the parent component?

Comment: Yes, next to the router-outlet in the template of the parent component.